# Cucumber - How configure it to use "--format pretty" as default?

Tags: configuration, cucumber

I'm starting learning rails, and having some troubles on configure cucumber to run my bdd tests.
What I want is run

> cucumber features

and this translate to

> cucumber features --format pretty

I tried to do this editing the config/cucumber.yml file (on a rails project).
Edited the line:

> default: <%= std_opts %> features

resulting on:

> default: <%= std_opts %> --format pretty features

But it make some erros happen:

> Using the default profile...
>   All but one formatter must use --out, only one can print to each stream (or STDOUT) (RuntimeError)

What I can do to make this option "--format pretty" default?
Also, is there any other good option to put as default to make result more clear?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found that this message:

> Using the default profile... All but
> one formatter must use --out, only one
> can print to each stream (or STDOUT)
> (RuntimeError)

is related to a cucumber bug, like posted on [this site](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/message/5261019#5261019)

My workaround was edit config/cucumber.yml and left it like this:

> std_opts = "--format rerun --out rerun.txt --strict --tags ~@wip"
>
> %>
>
> .....
>
> default: <%= std_opts %> -f pretty features

Now it worked. I think this is cloudy for me, and maybe some more comments on this (and maybe another) 'bug' would be nice. Also, another useful settings would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

default: <%= run_with_these_tags %> -f pretty -f json -o json_report/report.json